# git: Create new local branch without any local un-committed change

Tags: git

I'm on local branch A and did some changes without committing (they are not done). Then I want to create a new branch B (to work on something different) without bringing in the changes in branch A. If I do 'git checkout -b B', the changes in branch A will be brought to the new branch B. How can I avoid this? I want a brand new branch B without the changes in branch A, and I don't want to commit the changes in A at this moment because they are not finished.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can stash your changes before checking out a new branch.

```
git stash
git checkout -b B
```

If you have some new untracked files and you want them gone too, you can first add them (but not commit):

```
git add .
git stash
git checkout -b B
```

Later you will be able to untrack them by

```
git reset HEAD file
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `git stash` to store your changes in `A` away for the moment. Later on you can get them back with `git stash pop`.

You can list the stashes you made with `git stash list`. Also handy is viewing what changes are in a stash with `git stash show -p ..`.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ git branch
* a
  b
$ git stash
$ git checkout b
$ vim file0 file1
$ git commit -a -m'k done'
$ git checkout a
$ git stash pop
```