# Git - Went back to a previous commit and now want to write over the commits in front

Tags: git, github

I'm quite new to using Git.

I'm working on a repository where I tried to refactor the code and failed so I ended up going back 1 commit on the master branch and worked instead on where I was at before. I've now made changes that I want to keep and do not want to merge with the commit ahead. The commit ahead is already on a remote repository as well.

What would be the solution that wouldn't disturb the commits on both my local and remote repositories whilst keeping the changes I made and not merging?

Here is a git log for clarification. The HEAD, master commit is the one I just tried to do but wouldn't let me. the origin/master is the one that is the the tip of the branch and also on Github (I think.)

```
* bb1d222 (HEAD, master)
| * 832e8af (origin/master)
|/
* 3293d35
```

Comment: use git -push command and git -add <file> command

Comment: @fadfad Just to be clear: does commit `832e8af` correspond to your failed attempt at refactoring the code? Also, are you the only contributor to the repo?

Comment: @Jubobs Yes and Yes.

Comment: @Jubobs Thank you for your help and patience! I followed your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question and the follow-up comments, my understanding is that your repo's (recent) history looks as follows,

```
* bb1d222 (HEAD, master)
| * 832e8af (origin/master)
|/
* 3293d35
```

where commit `832e8af` corresponds to your failed attempt at refactoring the code.

Under the assumption that

1. you are the only contributor to the GitHub repository;
2. nobody else has ever cloned or forked the GitHub repository (there is [a way to find out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25607119/tidy-or-drop-git-history-for-release/25609876#25609876) whether that's the case); and
3. you would be happy to pretend that commit `832e8af` never existed and you would like to land in the following situation

   ```
   * bb1d222 (HEAD, master, origin/master)
   |
   * 3293d35
   ```

Then (and only then), you can simply do a force push

```
git push --force origin master
```

Be aware that a force push is generally considered to be **bad**, like [*crossing the streams*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jyaLZHiJJnE). Make sure that's really what you want to do; such an operation is complicated to reverse and has the potential to piss off your contributors (if any).

In most cases, it's preferable to revert the problematic commit (with git `revert`), as this, contrary to a force push, does not delete history and does not require a non-fastforward push.

Answer (score 1):

1) On your local master, execute `git reset HEAD~1`, and then `git stash`.  This will put the changes you made in bb1d222 in your stash.

2) Reset hard your local master branch to origin/master (`git reset --hard origin/master`)

3) On master, execute `git revert 832e8af`, which will introduce a new commit that will undo the changes you made in 832e8af.

4) `git stash pop` the changes you made in bb1d222 onto master, and commit them.

These steps will produce this commit graph, and will not rewrite history

`* (Commit introducing changes in bb1d222)
|
* (Commit reverting changes made in 832e8af
|
* 832e8af
|
* 3293d35`

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options:

1. You could create a [separate local branch and commit your changes to that local branch only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7494495/git-create-new-local-branch-without-any-local-un-committed-change). I prefer this method because then your changes are safely saved to that branch (unless your machine dies or you delete the branch).
2. Use the [git stash](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Stashing) to save your changes (your diff so to speak).

Comment: Preferably, I'd love for it to stay on the master branch which is where the problem is happening.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your situation. The remote version of the master branch is at commit 3. Your local version of the master branch is at commit 2 and you want to save your new changes to the local version of the master branch at commit 2? Do you want to completely discard the commit 3 on the remote master branch? If *not* you will need to resolve the merge conflicts.